# When I create a model, how am I able to access Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder 's find()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I noticed that in `web.php` I'm able to access `find()` of `Listing` model (that I created)

```
Route::get('listings/{id}',function($id){
return view('listing',[
    'listing'=>Listing::find($id)
]); });
```

When I checked `Listing` model I found that it extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`class. But I couldn't locate `find()` there. On further inspection I discovered that the above mentioned `find()` is a part of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class. Question is, how is my `Listing` model able to access `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`or does it happen through `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, if yes, how?

Comment: Look for these methods `public function newModelQuery` and `public function __call`

Comment: @Mehdi I checked `newModelQuery()` and found that it eventually returns an object of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class. But question remains, where does the method `newModelQuery()` gets invoked?

Comment: It called with __call magic method !!!!

Comment: @Mehdi I can definitely understand what `__call()` does but I still can't find where was `__call()` invoked? I checked `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` but couldn't find it. Could you help me locate where it happened?

Comment: it you want to learn about `__call()` look here: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-oop/php-__call/

Comment: @Sitethief I know `__call()` and it's usage but I'm unable to locate where it is being used and is calling `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` class?

Comment: @Mehdi Kindda got your point. Thanks man!

Comment: @Mehdi Could you share your email or some social media handle where we could connect?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel uses some "magic" ways to do thing like this.
You can see the way it does this by forcing an Exception in a find method like this:

```
    try {
        Model::findOrFail('aa');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
    }
```

This will show you the path the code took

It will look like this:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->findOrFail('aa')
#1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2335): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'findOrFail', Array)
#2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(2347): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('findOrFail', Array)
#3 /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Management/Controller.php(68): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic('findOrFail', Array)
#4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\Controller->method()
```

Comment: No need to keep looking, both __call() and __callStatic() are part of PHP's Magic Methods: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: True, but they need to be invoked somewhere? Where were they invoked is the question?

Comment: __call and __callStatic are invoked when you call a method that does not exists on that specific class, Laravel uses this as a trick to route to the correct methods. Look at the __call and __callStatic methods in the Model class, there is logic there to reroute to the correct methods.

Comment: In this specific case, you call `find()` static, but the class does not have a static method called `::find()`, thus `__callStatic()` get's called, Laravel then reroutes it to a non-static `->find()`, which also does not exists, thus we get to `__call()`, where Laravel has logic to route the call to `forwardCallTo()` in the ForwardsCalls trait on the Model class, there we get to `$object->{$method}(...$parameters);` which makes sure we end up in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->findOrFail('aa')`

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading it slowly and trying to get a grasp of the whole thing here. But thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see all query builder methods use the query method.
here is an example if you have a user model and want to find a user by id

```
$user = User::query()->find($id);
```

for me, my code editor is Php storm when I click the find method it forwards me to the Builder class

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
```

you will get all database query builder methods in this class

Comment: I'm using Sublime, I get suggestions and have to check various namespaces and then methods of various classes as to which method is relevant for me. I used var_dump() in `Collections` 's `find()` in order to check if that was the one being used but eventually discovered that `Builder` class' `find()` was being used here.

Comment: I recommend you use VSCODE because VSCODE has a lot of extensions
but if you want to stay with sublime use this Larvel package

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
this ide helper package has a lot of features check it